# Why is the underscore command _ useful?

Tags: cursor-motions

I'm a bit puzzeled as to why the underscore command `_`, which jumps to
the beginning of the (COUNT - 1)th line below the cursor, gets its own
key.  When would I use this rather than `+` or `^`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Good question!

As a motion by itself, you're right, `_` is not a particularly useful key. `:h _`

```
                            *_*
_  <underscore>     [count] - 1 lines downward, on the first non-blank
            character |linewise|.
```

The key word here is "linewise". So if your goal is to just move the cursor, then `^`, `j`, and `+` all get the job done, and there's not much point to `_`. But as an argument to an operator, `_` is super powerful.

A lot of double-key shortcuts are actually just shortcuts for `_`. For example,

```
dd -> d_
cc -> c_
yy -> y_
Y  -> y_
```

etc. Because it's a linewise motion, it basically selects the entire line to be operated on regardless of where your cursor starts, whereas `^` just goes from your character to the first non-blank.

It helps me when thinking about linewise vs blockwise motions to imagine that I'm pressing either `v` or `V` right before the motion. So I imagine `d^` to be equivalent to `v^d` and I imagine `d_` to be equivalent to `V_d` or `V^d`. Of course, you can also override a motion to force it to be linewise or characterwise. So `dv_` is actually exactly the same as `d^` or `v^d`, and `dVw` is like `Vwd` which is exactly like `d_`.

The reason it is specifically the "count-1th" line is so that `1dd` (which is really `d1_`) deletes one entire line, `2dd` (which is really `d2_`) deletes 2 entire lines, `3dd` deletes 3 entire lines, etc.

Comment: All right, but would I ever actually use it?  `dd` is easier than `d_` and `3yj` is easier than `4y_`.

Comment: @toothrot If you were creating your own operator and wanted to operate on the next **n** lines.

Comment: @Toothrot I guess I want to clarify that a little bit. In day to day vim editing, no it's really not particularly useful. I've almost never used it either. The reason it's useful is because it is the **definition** of a lot of useful commands. `dd` might be more convenient than `d_`, but that's because `dd` is just a mapping to `d_`. And it's also useful in vimscript.

Comment: Some actions that act on a "motion" may not have other shortcuts. Something like "gU_" will uppercase everything on the current line, even if the cursor is not at the start of the line.

Comment: @bmb What about `gUU`? I think it would be worthwhile to find an actual example where `<operator>_` would be used.

Comment: @Hotschke, Agreed. I thought I had :-) Thanks for the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

It's like <kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd> in Windows.

<kbd>0</kbd> goes to the first column but <kbd>_</kbd> to the first non-blank. A short form of <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for writing an answer. Note that the buddy of `0` is `^`. What differentiates `_` from these two is that it 1) accepts a count and 2) is a linewise motion as explained in [DJMcMayhem's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19746/4866). However, you can conveniently use `_` in place of `^`, especially when you have a keyboard layout where you would need to press `^` twice (which does constitute a valid use case).

Answer (score 0):

In some keyboard layouts, the <kbd>^</kbd> is a [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_keys). It produces the caret character only if the following key cannot be modified. This means it will wait for the next key to be pressed and put an accent on top of â ê î ô û and sometimes ŷ (and probably some more letters we don't care about).

While the accents shield those letters from the rain and can be used to create colorful names for your next fantasy rpg campaign, it's rather annoying when using Vim. Sometimes you really just want to jump to the first non-blank in the line with *a single key*.

A solution is to hit `_` instead of `^` (twice) rather than changing the keyboard layout. I sincerely doubt `_` was ever intended this way but it can be used this way.

Note that all the other nice features laid out in [DJMcMayhem's fine answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19746/4866), i.e. it being a *linewise* motion and accepting a count, are completely inconsequential if used as `^` *à la française*.